# Show that $y^2=x^3+1$ has infinitely many solutions over $\mathbb Z_p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

I first compared it with how I would solve this over the real numbers. You would  say:

- $y^2=\alpha$ has a solution for all $\alpha>0$, of which there are infinitely many.
- $x^3+1>0$ for all $x>-1$, of which there are also infinitely many.

However I can't seem to extend this way of thinking to $\mathbb Z_p$. I have a strong hunch that I need to use Hensel's Lemma in some way, but I just can't see how.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question. As far as I know $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a finite set, so your equation should have at last $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ solutions which is finite.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_p$ are $p$-adic integers. Hence the corresponding tag.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400709/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to show that the square root $\sqrt{x^3 + 1}$ exists in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for infinitely many $x$. To do this, show that if $p \mid x$, then

$$\sqrt{1 + x^3} = \sum_{n \ge 0} {1/2 \choose n} x^{3n}$$

converges in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. (The case $p = 2$ is, as usual, a bit different, but not so bad.)

Comment: The analogous argument to show that this equation has infinitely many solutions over the real numbers is to show that if $x < 1$ then this series converges in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by ${\frac 12}\choose n$?

Comment: @gebruiker: ${r \choose n} = \frac{r(r - 1) \dots (r - (n-1))}{n!}$ is a polynomial in $r$, so can be evaluated at any real (or even complex or, in this case, $p$-adic) $r$. Above I've used the Taylor series expansion $(1 + x)^r = \sum {r \choose n} x^n$.

Comment: I was surprised to notice that here, $2$ is not at all special. The series converges as long as $x$ is evaluated to an element of $p\Bbb Z_p$, any $p$.

Comment: @Lubin I don't believe $1/2\choose n$ makes much sense in $\mathbb Z_2$, so I don't quite see how this would solve that. Actually I'm a bit stuck on the $p=2$ all together.

Comment: @gebruiker: as I explained in your other question, it makes sense in $\mathbb{Q}_2$, and then you can calculate that if $2 \mid x$ then ${1/2 \choose n} x^{3n}$ ends up lying in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Right, @QiaochuYuan, as you said in your other answer, $\binom{1/2}n$ is necessarily in $\Bbb Q_2$, and certainly is not an element of $\Bbb Z_2$, but a suitable power of $2$ will of course knock it into $\Bbb Z_2$. Here’s a pleasing exercise for OP: show that $(1+4t)^{1/2}\in \Bbb Z[[t]]$.

Comment: I argued that $\vert 1/2-k\vert\leq \max \{\vert 1/2\vert; \vert k\vert\}=\vert 1/2\vert =2$. This implies that ${1/2\choose n}\leq \frac{\vert 1/2\vert ^n}{n!}\leq \vert 1/2\vert ^n =2^n$. This show that ${1/2\choose n}x^{3n}$ lies in $\mathbb Z_2$ when $2|x$. @Lubin I'll definitely look into that when I've got the time. Perhaps it will apear here as a "proof-verification" question. I'm much obliged for all the help from both of you anyway.

Comment: For future readers of these comments: the "other question" that is mentioned is [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1573680/145141).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of appealing either to the Binomial Theorem, as Qiaochu did, or to Hensel, you can do it “analytically”, knowing that in terms of the local uniformizing parameter $x$ at $(0,1)$, you must be able to expand $\eta=y-1$ as a series in $x$ with no constant term. Making that substitution, you get from $y^2=x^3+1$ to $\eta=(x^3-\eta^2)/2$, which you can look at as a recursive procedure for getting the expansion of $\eta$. The result is
$$
\eta=\frac12x^3 - \frac18x^6 + \frac1{16}x^9 - \frac5{128}x^{12} + \frac7{256}x^{15}-\cdots\,,
$$
and of course this is exactly the Binomial expansion. Just make a substitution $x\mapsto x_0$ for $x_0$ small enough, and you’ll get a convergent series.

I should say that this procedure is much more fun if you do it in the neighborhood of the point $\Bbb O$ at infinity of this curve, that is, $(0:1:0)$ projectively. There, the description of the curve in terms of $\xi=x/y$  and $\zeta=1/y$ is $\zeta=\xi^3+\zeta^3$, the l.u.p. being $\xi$, so you get a $\Bbb Z$-series for $\zeta$ in terms of $\xi$. Far as I can see, this expansion doesn’t come out of the Binomial Theorem.